# UnicodeDecodeError with using Biopython to obtain the abstract from efetch

Tags: python-3.x, biopython, pubmed

Recently, using the **Biopython** to extract some abstract from Pubmed.
My code is written in **Python3** as below:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "myemail@example.com"    # Always tell NCBI who you are


def get_number():    #Get the total number of abstract available in Pubmed
    handle = Entrez.egquery(term="allergic contact dermatitis ")
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    for row in record["eGQueryResult"]:
        if row["DbName"]=="pubmed":
            return int(row["Count"])


def get_id():    #Get all the ID of the abstract available in Pubmed
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="allergic contact dermatitis ", retmax=200)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    idlist = record["IdList"]
    return idlist

idlist = get_id()

for ids in idlist:    #Download the abstract based on their ID
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=ids, rettype="abstract", retmode="text")    # Retmode Can Be txt / json / xml / csv
    f = open("{}.txt".format(ids), "w")    # Create a TXT file with the name of ID
    f.write(handle.read())    #Write the abstract to the TXT file
```

I want to get **200** abstract, but it only succeeds in getting three or four abstract. Then, a error occur:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 288: illegal multibyte sequence
```

The `handle.read()` seem like having problem with those abstract, in which having certain symbol or words. I try to use `print` to know the class of `handle`:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=idlist, rettype="abstract", retmode="text")
print(handle)
```

The result is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='cp950'>
```

I have already searched lots of pages for the solution, but none of them works. Can anyone help?

Comment: See also https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1402

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works fine. It is encoding problem on your site. YOu can open file in bytes mode and encode the text in utf-8
You can try workaround like this:

```
for ids in idlist:    #Download the abstract based on their ID
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=ids, rettype="abstract", retmode="text")    # Retmode Can Be txt / json / xml / csv
    f = open("{}.txt".format(ids), "wb")    # Create a TXT file with the name of ID
    f.write(handle.read().encode('utf-8'))
```